# Strings não detectadas pelo Polylang.

Tags: wordpress, plugin, plugin-wordpress

Em um site wordpress para torná-lo bilíngue, estou usando o plugin Polylang, no entanto preciso traduzir a parte de Busca e não consigo. Essa página não é uma página listada no wordpress e na lista de Strings para traduzir, ela não aparece. Seria um placeholder escrito "Enter keywords". Como devo proceder?

Answer (score 0):

Olá, caro "user49915" :)

As strings do Polylang, servem para traduzir o que temas e plugins salvam no banco de dados, sabe, na tela de configuração deles...

Caso o placeholder não esteja nessa lista, ele estará nos arquivos php. Para traduzir estes conteúdos, você deve olhar nos arquivos de tradução (.po) do tema e plugins.

(https://polylang.pro/doc/strings-translation/)

Geralmente, estes arquivos ficam localizados nas pastas:

1.Temas

```
wp-content/languages/themes/{nome-do-tema}/{nome-do-tema}-{idioma}.po
```

2.Plugins

```
wp-content/languages/plugins/{nome-do-plugin}/{nome-do-plugin}-{idioma}.po
```

Caso o arquivo não exista, você pode copiar o arquivo .po da pasta /languages/ do tema ou plugin e colar lá.

Para editar um arquivo .po você pode utilizar:

- poedit https://poedit.net/download (app)
- loco-translate https://wordpress.org/plugins/loco-translate/ (plugin)

Quando você salvar o arquivo, estas ferramentas criaram um arquivo binário (.mo) que, finalmente, será lido pelo WordPress, seguindo a lógica dos caminhos das pastas que eu mencionei.

Caso se sinta curioso, no link abaixo tem a forma que desenvolvedores fazem para internacionalizar seus temas ou plugins:

https://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers